# Vorerst, vorläufig und bis auf Weiteres

Tags: difference, synonym

> **vorerst:**  zunächst einmal, fürs Erste
>
> **vorläufig:** nicht endgültig, aber bis auf Weiteres so [bestehend, verlaufend]; erst einmal, zunächst, fürs Erste
>
> **bis auf Weiteres:** vorerst, vorläufig

Quelle: Duden

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen diesen Wendungen? Sie alle klingen sehr ähnlich.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am Beispiel einer behördlichen Erlaubnis würde man sagen, dass eine **vorläufige** Erteilung eine "richtige" Erteilung der Erlaubnis noch nach sich zieht. Die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass die vorläufige Erlaubnis widerrufen wird, scheint im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch geringer, als bei einer Erlaubnis, die **vorerst** erteilt wird. Dieses Wort impliziert in Korrespondenz mit diesem Beispiel eine einhergehende Prüfung der Umstände der zu erteilenden Erlaubnis. **Bis auf weiteres** kann bedeuten, dass eine Erlaubnis wieder zurück gezogen werden kann, wenn äußere Umstände nicht mehr länger erfüllt sind. Eine Bewilligung der IST-Versteuerung bei Unternehmen beispielsweise wird vom Finanzamt nur *bis auf weiteres* erteilt, da diese bei zu hohem Umsatz oder Gewinn jeder Zeit wieder zurück genommen werden kann.

Der Gebrauch bzw. das allgemeine Verständnis ist also stark Kontextabhängig.